# Are there modular arguments for Legendre's conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, conjectures, sieve-theory

Legendre's conjecture says that there is always a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$ for every positive integer.

See :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture

Now I wonder why people believe it and what their arguments are.

I wonder about that because I know the reasons for similar conjectures like the prime twin conjecture.
Many conjectures in number theory (such as the prime twins) have arguments that are based on modular arithmetic and some kind of equidistribution.

But I do not see that here much. No convincing modular argument imo.
Nothing related to zeta functions either.

Note, I am not talking about for sufficiently large $n$ but for all positive integer $n$.
I am also not looking for checking the first 1000 integers, or assuming stronger conjectures like Cramer. Although Cramer has an argument of equidistribution.

I would like to point out that using $\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ is not such a good estimate for the density of primes.
Even $\pi(x) = Li(x) + O(\ln^3(x) \sqrt x)$ is stronger than what we can prove and yet weaker than the RH. Since the error term is larger than the square root, it is clear this (alone) is insufficient.
Hence this estimate $\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ does not make such a good argument.

So are there modular arguments for Legendre's conjecture ?
Or any kind of sieve ?

Comment: There are about $n^2/\log(n^2)$ primes up to $n^2$, and about $(n+1)^2/\log(n+1)^2$ primes up to $(n+1)^2$, and the difference between those two numbers goes to infinity with $n$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes for large n. But I wanted an argument for all n, see the OP

Comment: If Cramer is stronger and has an argument of equidistribution, is this not sufficient? Or are you really looking for some simple modular heuristic?

Comment: Maybe there's no argument for all $n$ of the type you want. There's no argument for a prime between $n$ and $1.3n$ for all $n$ because there isn't always a prime between $n$ and $1.3n$, but there is such a prime for all sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: The only heuristic for the twin prime conjecture is the 1/ln(n)-model. Modular arithmetics are useless since huge numbers can never be easily shown to be prime. The reason why this is believed is that a heuristic predicts that the largest prime gap that can occur is $O(\ln^2(p))$ , in fact $\ln^2(p)$ as an upper bound has not yet been refuted for $p>7$. The best proven upper bound is however much worse : for sufficiently large $p$ it is $p^{0.525}$

Comment: @Peter I disagree with that

Comment: @mick With what ?

Comment: @sku how does that violate the conjecture ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think in the limit $\frac{\pi(1.3n)}{\pi(n)} = 1.3$ but $\frac{\pi((n+1)^2)}{\pi(n^2)} = 1$. These scenarios are different, I think.

Comment: @Peter I do not believe that is the only heuristic.

Comment: It can also be restated as for arbitrary m that there exists a prime between m and m+4√m+4

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee true ... but trivial

Comment: Modular arithmetics cannot work since no matter how many prime factors we rule out, a huge enough number can still (and probably even still is) a composite number. So I again emphasize that such problems can never be solved with modular arithmetic arguments only.

Comment: @Peter that is a strong argument yes.